# Orocos components can not be compiled

Tags: ros, orocos

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am getting an error while compiling rtt orocos-toolchain package. I tried to reinstall latest updates from repository but seems it is still not working.

```
rootx@rootx-laptop:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros$ roscd rtt
rootx@rootx-laptop:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt$ rosmake
[ rosmake ] No package specified.  Building ['rtt']                                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rtt']                                                                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/rootx/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110221-115447                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rtt'] to:
['rtt']                                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages rtt.  This may take a few seconds.                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages                                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild                                                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                                                                         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                                                                                                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rtt [ make ]                                                                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                                                                              
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp                                                                                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                                                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole                                                                                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                                                                                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                                                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                                                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linest: 6.5 sec ]                                                                                                         [ 1 Active 9/10 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [  0%] Built target message
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  [ 44%] Built target orocos-rtt-gnulinux_dynamic
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  [ 47%] Built target rtt-typekit-gnulinux_plugin
  [ 49%] Built target orocos-rtt-mqueue-gnulinux_dynamic
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  [ 49%] [ 69%] Building CXX object build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/CMakeFiles/rtt-transport-mqueue-gnulinux_plugin.dir/MQLib.cpp.o
  Built target orocos-rtt-corba-gnulinux_dynamic
  [ 76%] make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  Built target rtt-marshalling-gnulinux_plugin
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  [ 76%] Built target rtt-transport-corba-gnulinux_plugin
  [100%] Built target rtt-scripting-gnulinux_plugin
  In file included from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/MQSerializationProtocol.hpp:50,
                   from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/MQLib.cpp:42:
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/binary_data_archive.hpp: In member function ‘void RTT::mqueue::binary_data_iarchive::load_binary(void*, size_t)’:
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/binary_data_archive.hpp:245: error: ‘stream_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::archive::archive_exception’
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/binary_data_archive.hpp:259: error: ‘stream_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::archive::archive_exception’
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/binary_data_archive.hpp: In member function ‘void RTT::mqueue::binary_data_oarchive::save_binary(const void*, size_t)’:
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/binary_data_archive.hpp:434: error: ‘stream_error’ is not a member of ‘boost::archive::archive_exception’
  make[3]: *** [build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/CMakeFiles/rtt-transport-mqueue-gnulinux_plugin.dir/MQLib.cpp.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[2]: *** [build/orocos-toolchain-rtt/rtt/transports/mqueue/CMakeFiles/rtt-transport-mqueue-gnulinux_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rtt written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/rootx/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110221-115447/rtt/build_output.log                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rtt [FAIL] [ 6.61 seconds ]                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rtt. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                                                  
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                                    
[ rosmake ] Built 10 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                                 
[ rosmake ] /home/rootx/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110221-115447                                                                                                     
rootx@rootx-laptop:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/kul-ros-pkg/stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/tags/orocos_toolchain_ros-0.1.5/rtt$
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.
Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9141/orocos-components-can-not-be-compiled/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The 'official' installation instructions are available on orocos.org (http://www.orocos.org/wiki/orocos/toolchain/getting-started) and contains a link to the orocos_toolchain_ros stack. In order to solve the error message you have, a couple of questions:

- are you sure you're working directory is clean? I see folder names like */tag/*-0.1.5... That's definitely not the latest version of the stack. Ruben released the 0.2.1 version last week.
- which ROS distribution are you using? As of diamondback, there are differences in the orocos_toolchain_ros stack between cturtle and diamondback. If you're using our git repository, use the cturtle branch for cturtle and the diamondback (or master) branch for diamondback.
- What platform are you working on?
- Which boost version are you using?

regards,

Steven

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0